# How to display the value of column in a html page?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table with one row and one column.The value stored is of type integer and I want to show this value in my HTML page.
The table name is 'count' and column name is 'order_number'.

Please tell me how to show this value in page.

Comment: What kind of table?  Is it a database table?  What kind of database?  How do you connect to it?  Are you using any server side scripting?  What language?

Comment: its a mysql database and i am using php for server side scripting.

Comment: Personally, I use MySQLi http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php but many will also recommend PHP Data Objects (PDO) http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: I didn't find any solution there.Please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

with php, you need to connect to mysql and query the DB and then echo the result.  here is an example with mysqli:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'your_database');

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}


$q=$mysqli->query("select * from `your_database`.`your_table` WHERE <some_condition>");
$cnt=0;
while($r=$q->fetch_assoc()) {
   $val[$cnt] = $r['field_name'];
    $cnt++;
}
$mysqli->close();

//Display first record
echo "The first record is: ".$val[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$cn=mysql_connect('localhost','user','password') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('test');
$sql="select order_number from count";
$read=mysql_query($sql,$cn)  or die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_array($read ) or die(mysql_error());
echo $row['order_number'];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "peter", "abc123");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

$db_selected = mysql_select_db("test_db",$con);

$sql = "SELECT order_number from count";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {   
        foreach ($row as $col => $val) {
            echo $col." = ".$val."<br>";
        }
    }
?>
```